# Moving of data from old table to another table PHP MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

i have some problem on creating a delete query on my code.

the flow will be, moving data from one table to another, im placing delete codes but its not working

my code

```
<?php

require_once('php/dbase.php');


$query="INSERT INTO tbl_user (username, password, access_type) VALUES ('".$_POST['user']."','".$_POST['pass']."','staff')";
if($mysqli->query($query)){ 
    $id=$mysqli->insert_id;

        $query2="INSERT INTO tbl_accounts (id,fname,mname,lname,gender,designation,s_question,s_answer) VALUES (".$id.",'".$_POST['fname']."','".$_POST['mname']."','".$_POST['lname']."','".$_POST['gender']."','".$_POST['designation']."','".$_POST['s_question']."','".$_POST['s_answer']."')";

        if($mysqli->query($query2)){
            $error=0;
            ?>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            alert("The account has been successfuly verified");
            location.href = "account_man.php";
            </script>

            <?php
        }else{
            $error=1;
            $message="Error";
            $data=array('error' =>$error , 'message'=>$message);
            echo json_encode($data);
        }

}else{

$error=1;
            $message="Error";
            $data=array('error' =>$error , 'message'=>$message);
            echo json_encode($data);    

}



?>
```

The old table is named "tbl_user_reco" and "tbl_accounts_reco".

Note: tbl_user_reco is auto increment

Delete Code

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "tdsw_db";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

// sql to delete a record
$sql = "DELETE FROM tbl_user_reco WHERE id= '.$id.'";
$sql = "DELETE FROM tbl_accounts_reco WHERE id= '.$id.'";

if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo "Record deleted successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error deleting record: " . mysqli_error($conn);
}

mysqli_close($conn);

        }else{
            $error=1;
            $message="Error";
            $data=array('error' =>$error , 'message'=>$message);
            echo json_encode($data);
        }
```

This is my merged Add and Delete Code and when i run it shows the "Record deleted successfully" but it never deletes anything but it adds data to the new table

```
<?php

require_once('php/dbase.php');


$query="INSERT INTO tbl_user (username, password, access_type) VALUES ('".$_POST['user']."','".$_POST['pass']."','staff')";
if($mysqli->query($query)){ 
    $id=$mysqli->insert_id;

        $query2="INSERT INTO tbl_accounts (id,fname,mname,lname,gender,designation,s_question,s_answer) VALUES (".$id.",'".$_POST['fname']."','".$_POST['mname']."','".$_POST['lname']."','".$_POST['gender']."','".$_POST['designation']."','".$_POST['s_question']."','".$_POST['s_answer']."')";

        if($mysqli->query($query2)){
            $error=0;
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "tdsw_db";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

// sql to delete a record
$sql = "DELETE FROM tbl_user_reco WHERE id= '.$id.'";
$sql = "DELETE FROM tbl_accounts_reco WHERE id= '.$id.'";

if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo "Record deleted successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error deleting record: " . mysqli_error($conn);
}

mysqli_close($conn);

        }else{
            $error=1;
            $message="Error";
            $data=array('error' =>$error , 'message'=>$message);
            echo json_encode($data);
        }

}else{

$error=1;
            $message="Error";
            $data=array('error' =>$error , 'message'=>$message);
            echo json_encode($data);    

}



?>
```

Comment: from which table you want to delete?? and where is your delete code??

Comment: the old table is "tbl_user_reco" and "tbl_accounts_reco"

Comment: $servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "tdsw_db";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

// sql to delete a record
$sql = "DELETE FROM tbl_user_reco WHERE id= '.$id.'";
$sql = "DELETE FROM tbl_accounts_reco WHERE id= '.$id.'";

Comment: if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo "Record deleted successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error deleting record: " . mysqli_error($conn);
}

mysqli_close($conn);

  }else{
   $error=1;
   $message="Error";
   $data=array('error' =>$error , 'message'=>$message);
   echo json_encode($data);
  }

Comment: please add the code part in question.

Comment: Have you verified SQL directly? Is it working?

Comment: the SQL is working correctly, the script is my problem, it adds the data to the new table but it never delete the data from the old table..

Comment: its deleting only in one table right??

Comment: @NiranjanNRaju i've seen the code "$sql" i already change it to

$sql=""
$sql1=""

but its not working, the flow will be delete two tables

Answer (score 0):

If you see this code, you are overwriting `$sql`, and its executing only second query,

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM tbl_user_reco WHERE id= '.$id.'";
$sql = "DELETE FROM tbl_accounts_reco WHERE id= '.$id.'";//$sql overwriting.

if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
```

Comment: did u check the above answer??