# How to transfer data from one sql table to another using php (delete previous data)

Tags: html

I am working on a school project in which i have to let students request a course and an admin has to approve them. i have made 2 tables namely "requests" and "courses" what im failing to achieve is to get the data transferred from the requests table to the courses table all the while deleting the selected entry from the requests table. Below is the code from the first page. and the image is from the second
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ihwqZ.png]

```html
<table border=1>
  <tr>
    <th>Student Name</th>
    <th>Student ID</th>
    <th>Course Name</th>
    <th>Course ID</th>
    <th>Course Faculty</th>
    <th>Course Timings</th>
    <th>Action</th>
  </tr>

  <?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "test";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM requests";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
       echo "<tr><td>". $row["u_name"]. "</td><td>". $row["u_id"]. "</td><td>". $row["c_name"]. "</td><td>". $row["c_id"]. "</td><td>" . $row["c_fac"] . "</td><td>".$row["c_time"]."</td><td><form action=cnext2.php method=POST><input type=submit value=Accept></td></form></tr>";
    } echo "</table>";
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: This sounds like homework help. But, I would recommend you do not delete the request record - rather, give it some properties. Set a flag when it is approved, and record the date and who did it. Then just insert into the new table.

Comment: visit it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33360057/moving-of-data-from-old-table-to-another-table-php-mysql

Comment: Not really homework, like i said its a project. It is important for the requests to be deleted after they have been approved, would be really grateful if someone could point me in the right direction

Comment: Pass the id of the accepted row in a hidden input field in the form. Get it in cnext2.php, get that row, copy the data, then delete that row.

Comment: @VörösAmadea could you please show me how?

Comment: I smell a lot of XSS here, don't forget to `htmlentities()` all your cell content before concatenating them to the HTML tags in the `echo`s lines and the `die` one. As for the question, your model seems wrong: just make 1 table with a `ENUM` column with values being either `'REQUESTED','APPROVED'` and change that value when teacher approves a request. That's all you need to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find out the name of the requests table's primary key field.
If it doesn't have a primary key, then add one to the table (make it an UNSIGNED INTEGER). Then fill this hidden field with the value of the primary key. (Also, close the form before closing the td, and note, that input fields are self-closing):

```
<form action='cnext2.php' method='POST'>
    <input type='hidden' name='request_id' value=".$row['PRIMARY KEY FIELD NAME HERE']." />
    <input type='submit' value='Accept' />
</form>
```

Then in cnext2.php:

```
if(isset($POST)){
    // When getting data from post or get request or other user input, sanitize it
    $id = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "request_id", FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
    $errors = array();

    if(!$id){
        errors[] = "No id submitted in request.";
    }
    // If you want to check other things, do it here and add error messages to the $errors array (validate your data)

    if(count($errors) > 0){
        foreach($errors as $error){
            echo $error . "<br />";
        }
    } else {
        // Create connection
        ...
        // Check connection
        ...
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM requests WHERE id = ".$id.";";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
            $sql2 = "INSERT INTO courses (field1, field2, ...) VALUES ('".$field1."', '".$field2."', ...);";
            $res2 = $conn->query($sql2);
            $sql3 = "DELETE FROM requests WHERE id = ".$id.";";
            $res3 = $conn->query($sql3);
            echo "Request with the id $id has been accepted.<br />";
        }
    }
}
```